# Is there a quick way to insert multiple rows into SQL Server when one of the values is going to be the same for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a rollback script (we write them for every DB Update, JIC) to insert multiple rows back into a table. The table is made up of two IDs, a BatchID and a RegistrationID (See screenshot-Sorry for the link, this is the first question I've had to ask). As you can see one batch can have multiple registrations. Other than coding:

...VALUES (RegistrationID,BatchID1),(The Same RegistrationID, BatchID2),...(The Same RegistrationID,BatchIDN) manually, is there another way to do this?

[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eas9m.png)

Comment: You can use any query in the source. In particular, you can have a subquery that `SELECT`s values and then `CROSS APPLY`s them with another selection of values.

Comment: If you have a table of numbers (and everyone should have this or know how to dynamically generate it - just search), you can simply cross join and apply a filter based on the number of iterations you want to insert.

Comment: If I`m following your question properly, then you could write INSERT INTO [table] SELECT command

Comment: There are many ways of doing so.what is your requirement like, give example and explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` and `select`:

```
insert into t (RegistrationID, BatchID)
    select @RegistrationID, v.BatchID
    from (values (@BatchID1), (@BatchID2), . . .
         ) v(BatchId);
```

Note:  This assumes that your values are constants.  Your `values` clause would not work otherwise (unless you are using a lateral join or correlated subquery).